# External link in navbar with scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, navbar

I have a navbar with links in it. The anchor link with scroll effect are working but external link or link to other page doesn't work,

Most likely the problem is in the js below (I tried to delete it and the external links work but it does not work the scroll) How can I change the js to insert external links in the menu?

```
function sliding() {
    $('.scrollTo, #navigation a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var full_url = this.href;
        var parts = full_url.split("#");
        var trgt = parts[1];

        $('body').scrollTo($('#' + trgt), 800, {offset: -80});

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are calling event.preventDefault(); for all #navigation a elements.

Make sure the scroll links have the .scrollTo Class and remove the #navigation a from the selector:

was

```
$('.scrollTo, #navigation a').click(function (event) {
```

should be:

```
$('.scrollTo').click(function (event) {
```